# Is it possible to access additional metadata info from a custom display or editor template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am aware that in a custom display or editor template I can get metadata about the model via `ViewData.ModelMetadata`, which has properties that indicate whether certain metadata attributes have been defined for the property, such as `IsRequired`, `DisplayName`, and so on. But is there anyway I can access custom metadata I've added to the property via custom attributes?

For example, say in my view I have a property like so:

```
[UIHint("Whizbang")]
[SomeAttribute("foobar")]
public string LeftWhizbang { get; set; }
```

And I have a custom display template named `Whizbang.cshtml` with the following content:

```
@model string

Left Whizbang Value: @Model
```

What I'd like to do is be able to determine whether the property `LeftWhizbang` is decorated with the attribute `SomeAttribute` and, if so, I'd like to access the attribute's `Message` property (say), namely the value "foobar".

I'd like to be able to do something like this in my template:

```
@model string

Left Whizbang Value: @Model

@{
    SomeAttributeAttribute attr = ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetAttributes(...);
    if (attr != null)
    {
        <text>... and the value is @attr.Message</text>
    }
}
```

Is this at all possible, or am I looking down a dead end?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure. First you'll need your attribute which implements `IMetadataAware` so that `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` knows about it

```
public class TooltipAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware {
    public TooltipAttribute(string tooltip) {
        this.Tooltip = tooltip;
    }

    public string Tooltip { get; set; }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata) {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["Tooltip"] = this.Tooltip;
    }
}
```

You can then access the attribute by creating a helper method:

```
public static IHtmlString TooltipFor<TModel, TValue>(
                             this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
                             Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) {
    var data = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TValue>(expression, html.ViewData);
    if (data.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("Tooltip"))
        return new HtmlString((string)data.AdditionalValues["Tooltip"]);

    return new HtmlString("");
}
```