# can I use AdditionalMetadata with editor template in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create a editor template for diferent type of data for example: for string I need a EditorTemplate for largeString and for shortstring

I see that the best way for me is using editor template. so can I use  AdditionalMetadata? for something like this?

```
 [UIHint("StringLarge")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("width", "50px")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

My editor Template StringLarge.cshtml

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.String> 

if("have AdditionalMetadata"){
@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { @class = "StringLarge" })
}
else
{
@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { @class = "StringShort" })
}
```

Can I do that or just create separtes EditorTemplate for stringLarge and StringShort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by writing a custom attribute implementing the [IMetadataAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imetadataaware.aspx) interface:

```
public class MyStringsAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    private readonly string _value;
    public MyStringsAttribute(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.TemplateHint = "Strings";
        metadata.AdditionalValues["someKey"] = _value;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[MyStrings("somevalue")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

and finally inside your custom editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Strings.cshtml`) you could check for the presence of this additional metadata:

```
@{
    var additionalMetadata = (string)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["someKey"];
}

@if (string.Equals(additionalMetadata, "somevalue"))
{
    ...    
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681534/is-it-possible-to-access-additional-metadata-info-from-a-custom-display-or-edito

like in here right? I thought it could be more simpler like you do here in javascript

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681107/asp-net-mvc-editortemplates-uihint-with-parameters

Comment: Yeap, implementing `IMetadataAware` is one way to achieve that or using the `[AdditionalMetadata]` attribute. It's really up to you to decide which approach suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

using [AdditionalMetadata]

ViewModel:

```
 [UIHint("StringCorto")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("style", "width:100px")] 
    public string Nit { get; set; }
```

Editor Template:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.String> 


@{
    this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.Add("class", "StringCorto");
}


@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues)
```