# Is it possible to access an additional custom model property from viewdata.modelmetadata.properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

On a specific View, I pass in a new model to a partial view via:

`@Html.Partial("view.cshtml", new Model1())`

Then on the partial I need to access all of its properties, and attributes, including a new custom attribute I made.

My new attribute uses MetadataAware:

```
public class ReportDescriptionAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public ReportDescriptionAttribute(string resourceKey)
    {
        this.ReportDescription = resourceKey;
    }

    public string ReportDescription { get; set; }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["ReportDescription"] = this.ReportDescription;
    }
}
```

so on my model I can now use `[ReportDescription("resourcekey")]`

But in my partial view, when I use `@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)` it does not show up.

*I also created the HTML helper class, as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681534/is-it-possible-to-access-additional-metadata-info-from-a-custom-display-or-edito) very similar question, but  cannot get it to work.

Thoughts? Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to access the values in `AdditionalValues` - `foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> value in ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues)` or `ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["ReportDescription"]`

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that and tried it, but my custom attribute does not show up.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show your helper class as well (its late but I'll have a look in the morning)

Comment: Your solution worked just fine!  I realized the Additional Attributes were on each property, instead of the parent ModelMetaData.  Thanks for your help.  I'll post my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above, Stephen was able to point me in the right direction.  My additional attribute was there the whole time, and I didn't even need the helper class, just the IMetaDataAware.

```
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    <div style="margin:10px">
        <strong>@(property.DisplayName)</strong>
        <br />
        @foreach (var addProp in property.AdditionalValues)
        {
            if (addProp.Key == "ReportDescription")
            {
                <span>@addProp.Value</span>
            }

        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Side note:You can replace your inner `foreach` loop with `if (propery.AdditionalMetadata.ContainsKey("ReportDescription") { <span>propery.AdditionalValues["ReportDescription"]</span> }`